# Convert SQL string into array ActionScript 3

Tags: sql, arrays, actionscript-3

Let's say I have an array from an SQL result which has been converted into a string with the following characters:

```
array(3) {
["p_1"]=>
int(1)
["p_2"]=>
int(2)
["p_3"]=>
int(3)
```

I am trying to work out how I might convert this string into an Array Collection or an array with matching labels and data values. For example:

```
new ArrayCollection(
[{ label:"P1", data:1 },
{ label:"P2", data:2 },
{ label:"P3", data:3 }]);
```

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have control over that first string or are you getting it from a third party?

Comment: Yes I have control over it but I am using PHP 4. So room to use JSON is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first code sample is the result of `var_dump()`ing an array in PHP. You should convert it to a usable format first (e.g. with PHP's `json_encode()` and then use the relevant library within AS3 to convert it back to an object or array (Flash Player 11 includes a [set of classes for working with JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html)).

Comment: I am using PHP4 at the moment (legacy system) so I am looking into whether I can use json_encode() in PHP4.

Comment: @user1884723 You can get a script that will add JSON functions for you if they're lacking.

Comment: Something along these lines? http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped enourmously.